# Constraint Layout returns wrong id in the hierarchy

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm working on Constraint layout that has has two image buttons with different ideas placed in side of each other like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<!-- here are some views -->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/openCamera"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/camera_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scaleX="3.7"
    android:scaleY="3.7"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/openGallery"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logoText"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/openGallery"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gallery_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scaleX="3.7"
    android:scaleY="3.7"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/openCamera"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logoText"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gallery_icon" />

<!-- other views -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the problem here is that when I click ether buttons I get the *id* of the second button (as when I swap their positions I always get the second *id*).

**how I fix this issue?**

-- what I tried was:

- not implementing `View.OnClickListener` interface and checked it still having same problem.
- I was working on relative layout fine but it was having a lot of hierarchy so I switched to Constraint layout.

the java code is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageButton openCameraButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.openCamera);
    ImageButton openGalleryButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.openGallery);
    openCameraButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    openGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.openCamera:
            someMethod();
            break;
        case R.id.openGallery:
            antherMethod();
            break;
        default:
            Log.v(TAG, "HOW YOU GET THERE!!!");
            break;
    }
}
```

what i get from debugging mode:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtXGg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this answer work for me on ConstrainLayout

what i did is adding width greater than 0 (*which is 100 here*) for the Image button. don't know why but it works now!!!

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/openCamera"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/camera_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scaleX="3.7"
    android:scaleY="3.7"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/openGallery"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logoText"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_icon" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/openGallery"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gallery_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scaleX="3.7"
    android:scaleY="3.7"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/openCamera"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logoText"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gallery_icon" />
```

**hoping if anyone has a better answer or fixing this problem.**

Comment: posted this as an issue 
https://github.com/googlecodelabs/constraint-layout/issues/59

Answer (score 0):

i saw this code

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/openCamera"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/camera_button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:scaleX="3.7"
    android:scaleY="3.7"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/openGallery"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logoText"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera_icon" />
```

try to remove this line

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Hope this help

Comment: removed it didn't do anything

Comment: i added it as i was checking multiple things before posting the question and forgot the remove it:)

Comment: then please check "break" is exist after case R.id.openCamera:
            someMethod(); i think the main reason second id always called because you forgot to make break on first case

Comment: break making it's job i debugged it plus i've tried to use onClickListener() directly on the button without using onClick from View.OnClickListener interface and still getting same error.
i also tried to use LinearLayout to nest those 2 buttons but still same issue!

Comment: And try to remove focusable for each button in xml. You dont need it also

Comment: tried to remove focusable and build get same error and tried to remove clickable and the error still there!!!

Comment: updated the question with screenshot from debugging mode and there's much printed in logcat

Comment: check my answers you may get to why this happens!

Answer (score 0):

It is because the callback method onClick is linked to the first button.
Remove the line android:onClick="onClick"  from the  xml

Comment: didn't help; as i was trying multiple things and forgot to remove it